# Error while updating Drupal with drush

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I want to update my drupal, but when I am executing *drush up* there is an error:

> The tb_sirate_starter directory could not be found within the profiles directory at /var/www/html/project/sites/all/modules/tb_megamenu, perhaps the project is enabled but has been deleted from disk.

I have *tb_megamenu* and I tried to install *tb_sirate_starter* but the error is not disappearing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The update might have moved files around and failed before the system table in Drupal's database was updated.

Try installing the Regsitry Rebuild project (if not installed already) and running a registry rebuild: https://www.drupal.org/project/registry_rebuild.

You can see if you already have it installed and run it by executing:

```
drush rr
```

If you do not have it installed already, go ahead an install it and follow directions on the project page to run it.

Once that is complete, run an updb and cache clearas well:

```
drush updb -y
drush cc all
```

Be sure to make a backup of your database and codebase before doing any of this (as you should have before running drush up in your original attempt and as you should before any and all upgrades).